# Is there a way to produce an definite integral based off a specific symmetry.

Tags: definite-integrals, elementary-functions

A method to evaluate an integral such as $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$ is to make the substitution $x=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$ to receive $$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln2}{1+x^2} dx-I$$ which makes the integral trivial. I am trying to figure out the inverse problem. Given a differentiable bijection $\phi : [a,b] \to [a,b]$. I am trying to find an integral $$I=\int_a^b f(x) dx$$ that can be evaluated by the sustitution $x=\phi(u)$. After this substitution I want something of the form $$I=\int_a^b g(x)dx +cI$$ where $g$ has an elementary primitive. This gives the equation $$f\circ \phi \cdot  \phi'=g+cf$$ which is equivalent to the condition that $$f\circ \phi \cdot  \phi'-cf$$ has an elementary primitive. Now from Liouville's theorem we get 
$$f\circ \phi \cdot  \phi'-cf= \sum_i c_i \frac{g_i'}{g_i}+h'$$ where $g_1,..., g_n $ and $h$ are in an elementary field containing $ f$ and $ \phi$

Looking back at my example up the top where $\phi(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, we get the condition that $$\frac{-2}{(1+x)^2}f\left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right ) -cf(x)= \sum_i c_i \frac{g_i'}{g_i}+h'$$ where $g_1,..., g_n $ and $h$ are in $C(x,\frac{1-x}{1+x},f)$

Which I have no idea how to attack except already knowing a solution. 
This question is more of an exploration, so any links to resources on the subject or ideas related to it are welcome.

Just to be clear my question is how I can create an integral that can be evaluated by a particular substitution. I have outlined my (incomplete) approach and given an example of the type of thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a linear functional equation

$$ g(x) = \phi'(x) f(\phi(x)) - c f(x) \tag 1$$

In general functional equations are hard to solve, but there are some nice cases:

The function $\phi(x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ is a nice example because it's an involution: $\phi(\phi(x)) = x$.  Substituting $\phi(x)$ for $x$ in the functional equation gives

$$ g(\phi(x)) = \phi'(\phi(x)) f(x) - c f(\phi(x)) = \frac{f(x)}{\phi'(x)} - c f(\phi(x)) \tag 2$$

and you can solve (1) and (2) for $f(x)$: if $c^2 \ne 1$,

$$ f(x) = \frac{c g(x) + \phi'(x) g(\phi(x))}{1 - c^2} $$

However, in your example you want $c = -1$, which makes the system singular,
and imposes a condition $g(x) = \phi'(x) g(\phi(x))$.

Comment: This is brilliant.

Comment: One question, where did you get $\psi '(\psi (x))=\frac{1}{\psi' (x)$

Comment: Differentiate $\phi(\phi(x))=x$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense